# installation of JBoss in Eclipse while Tomcat is already installed

Tags: eclipse, jboss

i m using Tomcat server and i want to add JBoss Server into my Eclipse,i'd tried to import Zip file of JBOSS but i did not able to make it.
what to do & How to install JBoss Server in Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Starting+JBoss+AS+from+Eclipse+with+JBoss+Tools) is the tutorial on how to do that. You basically need to add new server and point Eclipse to the location of the unzipped folder which contains your server (that applies for all of them, not just JBoss). You should also do some research before asking because Google is full of solutions for this particular question.

Comment: And what is your problem exactly?

Comment: its asking for duplicate location